# Como não usar onload no body com este codigo?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber como faço para usar o seguinte codigo:

```
function startTime() {
    var dateString = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Sao_Paulo"});
    $('#txt').attr("data-original-title", dateString, 1000);
    setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
}
```

Sem ter que adicionar isso no body:

```
<body onload="startTime();">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode invocar a função `startTime` quando a página for carregada.

```
<script>
  function startTime() {
    let dateString = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Sao_Paulo"});
$('#txt').attr("data-original-title", dateString, 1000);
setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
  }

  window.addEventListener('load', startTime)
</script>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a propriedade [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) que executa uma função assim que todo o conteudo da página é carregado, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
<script>
  function startTime() {
    let dateString = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Sao_Paulo"});
    $('#txt').attr("data-original-title", dateString, 1000);
    setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
  }

   window.onload = startTime;
</script>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!